# need help solving com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds not found

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, admob, ads, google-mobile-ads

After trying to load my banner ad I get the following errors:

1. `AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds`
2. `AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.UnityAdListerner`

by the way I use the dummy app id in all the scripts for example in **AndroidManifest.xml** and in the script which loads the banner ad.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have android library with this classes. They should be in **Assets/Plugins/Android** folder